# A summary of all Google Apps Script triggers in my account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

Is there any place where I can see the summary of all the Apps Script timed triggers installed for all my documents on Google Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: the triggers are now in the "edit" menu, see below answer for illustration.

Go to the script editor, choose "Resources" and you'll get a result as illustrated below :

[image]

Then you will see a scrollable list with all the triggers, including the timers, the event triggers, everything :

[image]

Comment: I don't think so, it shows only the name of the function

Comment: Changes : Refer Below Menu

Answer (score 2):

Changes :

Go to the script editor, choose "Edit" and you'll get a result as illustrated below :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would update this answer, since Google now has a new dashboard for Apps Scripts. None of the other answers still work. If you are in any script and click on the Apps Script logo/link at the top, you will go to your Apps Script control panel. From there, there is a link to My Triggers on the left.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

2023: The GAS triggers for your account can now be accessed from this URL

https://script.google.com/home/triggers