# I am using GSuite. I uninstalled Goobric add-on from sheets and get this email EVERY DAY

Tags: google-workspace

I am using GSuite. I tried the Goobric/Doctopus add-on last year and uninstalled it from Sheets because I didn't like it. I still get this same email EVERY DAY. ​

```
Your script, Goobric Web App, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.  
Summary:  Error Message Count Authorization is required to perform that action. 24

​1/6/18 7:14 PM checkFixFormTrigger Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  1/6/18 7:14 PM
1/6/18 8:14 PM  checkFixFormTrigger Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  1/6/18 8:14 PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a similar message related to Goobric the past few days. While I couldn't find the offending document, I was able to remove the trigger using these steps:

Open a Google Doc or sheet, and choose Tools->Script Editor.

Choose "Edit" and you'll get a result as illustrated below :

[image: Show all triggers on your user account]

This will show you all the triggers your account has set up. While it doesn't identify the documents that have the trigger installed, you should be able to identify the offending trigger and click the X on the left to remove it.

source: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065290/a-summary-of-all-google-apps-script-triggers-in-my-account)

Comment: Glad to hear it! Looks like you're new to StackOverflow. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on other questions which still don't have answers.